# vertical spacing between enumerate and multicol increase

Tags: spacing, enumerate, multicol

I would like to slightly increase the vertical space between the fraction answers as currently it looks wrong (ie the spacing between and a b, c and d, and e and f:
[image: spacing]

any suggestions on formatting or how i could improve it i would appreciate also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=558pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item \quad $\displaystyle 2$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{16}{25}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{11}{12}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{23}{10}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vertical space command **vspace** in order to do that.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=558pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item \quad $\displaystyle 2$
      \vspace{0.5cm}
\item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}$
\item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{16}{25}$
      \vspace{0.5cm}
\item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{11}{12}$        
\item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{23}{10}$
              \vspace{0.5cm}
\item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which generates something like this:

[image]

Comment: This generates uneven spacing, since the text of item (a) is less tall than the others; adjusting `\baselineskip` should produce more consistent results.

Comment: can you throw us some example markup Chris :) please

Answer (score 0):

You can use more recent and powerful `enumitem` package. It emulates the functionality of `enumerate` package if you pass `shortlabels`option like

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
```

Now, you can adjust the `itemsep`:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(a),itemsep=0.5\baselineskip]
```

so that the spacing is consistent.  Further, it will be better to add some vertical phantom space in

```
\item \quad \vphantom{$\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}$}$\displaystyle 2$
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, paperwidth=992pt, paperheight=558pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\LARGE
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[(a),itemsep=0.5\baselineskip]
    \item \quad \vphantom{$\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}$}$\displaystyle 2$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{16}{25}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{11}{12}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{23}{10}$
    \item \quad $\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]